# Jpanel calling a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jpanel

I'm calling this class from another class with setContentPane(new Gamepanel()).
Why the thread t1 is not calling the run method?

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static int WIDTH = 1024;
    public static int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    private Thread t1;
    boolean running;


    public void addNotify(){
        Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        running = true;
        t1.start();
    }


    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(200, 200, 50, 50);
    }


    public void run() {
        while (running){
            System.out.println("Runs");
    }
}
```

EDIT

Well, in fact initializing the Thread did the trick. Like that

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static int WIDTH = 1024;
    public static int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    private Thread t1;
    boolean running;


    public void addNotify(){
        Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        running = true;
        t1 = new Thread(this);
        t1.start();
     }



    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(200, 200, 50, 50);
     }


     public void run() {
         while (running){
         System.out.println("Runs");
         }

     }

}
```

I was assuming that this was a right way to start putting a game loop in the start method.
I'm planning to go JFrame+JPanel+threaded game loop (input+update+draw).Am I wrong?

Comment: This should throw a NullPointerException since you never initialise `t1`... You would need a `t1 = new Thread(this);` somewhere. Note that whatever you are trying to achieve, there is almost certainly a better way.

Comment: Threads and swing components don't mix. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.
What Thread1 should do ? 
Please give us details about the way you call your Thread T1, and how you build your class.
By the way you put T1 in private access and I don't see any getter/setter in your class. 
If you want to manipulate it you'll have to define some methods.

If you don't give an object which inherits of a Thread object it's sure it won't work. 
Please see : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html
Thread class implements itself Runnable interface.

I conclusion with your code is impossible to tell you what is wrong, they have too many fields of problems.

Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the thread, it must throw you a `NullPointerException`.
Try that
In your main method

```
 t1=new Thread(new GamePanel());
 t1.start();
```

//not in notify or modify it according to your req.
Unclear question